# Optimize MySQL View that uses self-join

Tags: mysql, view, self-join

I have this table which needs to perform a self-join:

```
+----+------+-------+-----+------+-------+-----------+---------+------+
| id | type | panel | row | port | cable | cablePort | conType | B_id |
+----+------+-------+-----+------+-------+-----------+---------+------+
|  1 |    1 | A     |   1 |    1 |       |           |       1 |      |
|  2 |    1 | A     |   1 |    2 |       |           |       1 |      |
|  3 |    1 | A     |   1 |    3 |       |           |       1 |      |
|  4 |    1 | A     |   1 |    4 |       |           |       1 |      |
|  5 |    1 | A     |   1 |    5 |       |           |       1 |      |
|  6 |    1 | A     |   1 |    6 |       |           |       1 |      |
|  7 |    1 | A     |   1 |    7 |       |           |       1 |      |
|  8 |    1 | A     |   1 |    8 |       |           |       1 |      |
|  9 |    1 | A     |   1 |    9 |       |           |       1 |      |
| 10 |    1 | A     |   1 |   10 |       |           |       1 |      |
+----+------+-------+-----+------+-------+-----------+---------+------+
```

(self join needs to be performed for id and B_id)

which would like result to this table:

```
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+
| a_id | a_type | a_panel | a_row | a_port | a_cable | a_cablePort | a_conType | b_B_id | b_type | b_panel | b_row | b_port | b_cable | b_cablePort | b_conType |
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+
|    1 |      1 | A       |     1 |      1 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
|    2 |      1 | A       |     1 |      2 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
|    3 |      1 | A       |     1 |      3 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
|    4 |      1 | A       |     1 |      4 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
|    5 |      1 | A       |     1 |      5 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
|    6 |      1 | A       |     1 |      6 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
|    7 |      1 | A       |     1 |      7 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
|    8 |      1 | A       |     1 |      8 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
|    9 |      1 | A       |     1 |      9 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
|   10 |      1 | A       |     1 |     10 | NULL    | NULL        |         1 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        | NULL      |
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

(please note that I haven't specified any B_id on this record)

below is my table structure:

```
╔═══════════════╦═════════════╦══════╦═════╦═════════╦════════════════╗
║     Field     ║    Type     ║ Null ║ Key ║ Default ║     Extra      ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════╬══════╬═════╬═════════╬════════════════╣
║     id        ║ int(11)     ║ NO   ║ PRI ║ NULL    ║ auto_increment ║
║     type      ║ varchar(45) ║ YES  ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║     panel     ║ varchar(45) ║ YES  ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║     row       ║ varchar(45) ║ YES  ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║     port      ║ varchar(45) ║ YES  ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║     cable     ║ varchar(45) ║ YES  ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║     cablePort ║ varchar(45) ║ YES  ║     ║ NULL    ║                ║
║     conType   ║ varchar(45) ║ YES  ║ MUL ║ NULL    ║                ║
║     B_id      ║ int         ║ YES  ║ MUL ║ NULL    ║                ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════════╩══════╩═════╩═════════╩════════════════╝
```

and finally here's my View that executes the self-join.

```
select distinct
  `a`.`id`        AS `a_id`,
  `a`.`type`      AS `a_type`,
  `a`.`panel`     AS `a_panel`,
  `a`.`row`       AS `a_row`,
  `a`.`port`      AS `a_port`,
  `a`.`cable`     AS `a_cable`,
  `a`.`cablePort` AS `a_cablePort`,
  `a`.`conType`   AS `a_conType`,
  `a`.`B_id`      AS `b_B_id`,
  `b`.`type`      AS `b_type`,
  `b`.`panel`     AS `b_panel`,
  `b`.`row`       AS `b_row`,
  `b`.`port`      AS `b_port`,
  `b`.`cable`     AS `b_cable`,
  `b`.`cablePort` AS `b_cablePort`,
  `b`.`conType`   AS `b_conType`
from `mmr` `a`
  left join `mmr` `b`
    ON (`a`.`id` = `b`.`B_id`)
```

The problem is that the execution of my view for data extraction is unacceptable. It takes around 1 minute or more just to extract 10000 records.

Could you advise me on how will I be able to optimize my query and what's causing the slow execution of data extraction.

Additional:

I also created another view that will extract data from the view above. This view would further need to manipulate the data and present more detailed data for viewing.

```
select 
        `a`.`a_id` AS `a_id`,
        `a`.`a_type` AS `a_type`,
        `a`.`a_panel` AS `a_panel`,
        `a`.`a_row` AS `a_row`,
        `a`.`a_port` AS `a_port`,
        `a`.`a_cable` AS `a_cable`,
        `a`.`a_cablePort` AS `a_cablePort`,
        `a`.`a_conType` AS `a_conType`,
        `a`.`a_conTypeDesc` AS `a_conTypeDesc`,
        `a`.`b_B_id` AS `b_B_id`,
        `a`.`b_type` AS `b_type`,
        `a`.`b_panel` AS `b_panel`,
        `a`.`b_row` AS `b_row`,
        `a`.`b_port` AS `b_port`,
        `a`.`b_cable` AS `b_cable`,
        `a`.`b_cablePort` AS `b_cablePort`,
        `a`.`b_conType` AS `b_conType`,
        `a`.`b_conTypeDesc` AS `b_conTypeDesc`,
        (case
            when
                ((`a`.`b_panel` = `b`.`b_panel`)
                    and (`a`.`b_row` = `b`.`b_row`))
            then
                concat(`a`.`b_panel`,
                        _latin1'-',
                        `a`.`b_row`,
                        _latin1'(',
                        (case
                            when (cast(`a`.`b_port` as signed) > cast(`b`.`b_port` as signed)) then `b`.`b_port`
                            else `a`.`b_port`
                        end),
                        _latin1',',
                        (case
                            when (cast(`a`.`b_port` as signed) < cast(`b`.`b_port` as signed)) then `b`.`b_port`
                            else `a`.`b_port`
                        end),
                        _latin1')')
            when
                ((`a`.`b_row` <> `b`.`b_row`)
                    and (`a`.`b_cablePort` <> _latin1''))
            then
                concat(`a`.`b_panel`,
                        _latin1'-',
                        `a`.`b_row`,
                        _latin1'(',
                        `a`.`b_port`,
                        _latin1'),',
                        `b`.`b_row`,
                        _latin1'(',
                        `b`.`b_port`,
                        _latin1')')
            else concat(`a`.`b_panel`,
                    _latin1'-',
                    `a`.`b_row`,
                    _latin1'(',
                    `a`.`b_port`,
                    _latin1')')
        end) AS `mmrport`
    from
        `vw_details` `a`
        left join `vw_details` `b` ON (`a`.`b_cable` = `b`.`b_cable`)
            and (`a`.`b_cablePort` = `b`.`b_cablePort`)
            and (`a`.`b_B_id` <> `b`.`b_B_id`)
            and (`a`.`b_type` = `b`.`b_type`)
            and (`a`.`b_panel` = `b`.`b_panel`)
            and (`a`.`b_conType` = `b`.`b_conType`)
```

(** with the view above, the data extraction duration goes very unacceptable)

result of view is like below:

```
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
| a_id | a_type | a_panel | a_row | a_port | a_cable | a_cablePort | a_conType | a_conTypeDesc  | b_B_id | b_type | b_panel | b_row | b_port | b_cable | b_cablePort | b_conType | b_conTypeDesc  |  mmrport   |
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
|  689 |      1 | A       |    69 |      9 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected |    698 |      1 | A       |    70 |      8 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected | A-70(7,8)  |
|  690 |      1 | A       |    69 |     10 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected |    697 |      1 | A       |    70 |      7 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected | A-70(7,8)  |
|  691 |      1 | A       |    70 |      1 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected |    699 |      1 | A       |    70 |      9 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected | A-70(9,10) |
|  692 |      1 | A       |    70 |      2 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected |    700 |      1 | A       |    70 |     10 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected | A-70(9,10) |
|  697 |      1 | A       |    70 |      7 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected |    690 |      1 | A       |    69 |     10 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected | A-69(9,10) |
|  697 |      1 | A       |    70 |      7 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected |    690 |      1 | B       |    30 |      8 |       1 |           2 |         4 | Disconnected   | B-30(8,10) |
|  698 |      1 | A       |    70 |      8 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected |    689 |      1 | A       |    69 |      9 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected | A-69(9,10) |
|  698 |      1 | A       |    70 |      8 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected |    689 |      1 | B       |    30 |     10 |       1 |           2 |         4 | Disconnected   | B-30(8,10) |
|  699 |      1 | A       |    70 |      9 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected |    691 |      1 | A       |    70 |      1 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected | A-70(1,2)  |
|  699 |      1 | A       |    70 |      9 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected |    691 |      1 | B       |    30 |      9 |       1 |           1 |         4 | Disconnected   | B-30(7,9)  |
|  700 |      1 | A       |    70 |     10 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected |    692 |      1 | A       |    70 |      2 |       1 |           1 |         3 | Interconnected | A-70(1,2)  |
|  700 |      1 | A       |    70 |     10 |       1 |           2 |         3 | Interconnected |    692 |      1 | B       |    30 |      7 |       1 |           1 |         4 | Disconnected   | B-30(7,9)  |
+------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+----------------+--------+--------+---------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+----------------+------------+
```

**New:
Question: How come just a simple self-join on this table for 15000 records takes a long time to process in MySQL?**

If you could suggest any work-around for this I will greatly appreciate.

Comment: use group by instead of distinct. And why do you even need self join when the records coming are null

Comment: Why is `a_id` a `INT` and `B_id` a `VARCHAR(45)`?. I mean it doesn't make sense to join from a `varchar` to an `int`? There would be an implicit conversion which takes time

Comment: try explain our query and post the result in question.

Comment: Oh yeah... that should be B_id should be int also, will edit on my post.

Comment: @raheelshan supposed that the B_id details are not null and is actually and instance of the id itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the condition of join to where in the first step

```
select 
    `a`.`a_id` AS `a_id`,
    `a`.`a_type` AS `a_type`,
    `a`.`a_panel` AS `a_panel`,
    `a`.`a_row` AS `a_row`,
    `a`.`a_port` AS `a_port`,
    `a`.`a_cable` AS `a_cable`,
    `a`.`a_cablePort` AS `a_cablePort`,
    `a`.`a_conType` AS `a_conType`,
    `a`.`a_conTypeDesc` AS `a_conTypeDesc`,
    `a`.`b_B_id` AS `b_B_id`,
    `a`.`b_type` AS `b_type`,
    `a`.`b_panel` AS `b_panel`,
    `a`.`b_row` AS `b_row`,
    `a`.`b_port` AS `b_port`,
    `a`.`b_cable` AS `b_cable`,
    `a`.`b_cablePort` AS `b_cablePort`,
    `a`.`b_conType` AS `b_conType`,
    `a`.`b_conTypeDesc` AS `b_conTypeDesc`,
    (case
        when
            ((`a`.`b_panel` = `b`.`b_panel`)
                and (`a`.`b_row` = `b`.`b_row`))
        then
            concat(`a`.`b_panel`,
                    _latin1'-',
                    `a`.`b_row`,
                    _latin1'(',
                    (case
                        when (cast(`a`.`b_port` as signed) > cast(`b`.`b_port` as signed)) then `b`.`b_port`
                        else `a`.`b_port`
                    end),
                    _latin1',',
                    (case
                        when (cast(`a`.`b_port` as signed) < cast(`b`.`b_port` as signed)) then `b`.`b_port`
                        else `a`.`b_port`
                    end),
                    _latin1')')
        when
            ((`a`.`b_row` <> `b`.`b_row`)
                and (`a`.`b_cablePort` <> _latin1''))
        then
            concat(`a`.`b_panel`,
                    _latin1'-',
                    `a`.`b_row`,
                    _latin1'(',
                    `a`.`b_port`,
                    _latin1'),',
                    `b`.`b_row`,
                    _latin1'(',
                    `b`.`b_port`,
                    _latin1')')
        else concat(`a`.`b_panel`,
                _latin1'-',
                `a`.`b_row`,
                _latin1'(',
                `a`.`b_port`,
                _latin1')')
    end) AS `mmrport`
from
    `vw_details` `a`
    left join `vw_details` `b` ON (`a`.`b_cable` = `b`.`b_cable`)

WHERE (`a`.`b_cablePort` = `b`.`b_cablePort`)
    and (`a`.`b_B_id` <> `b`.`b_B_id`)
    and (`a`.`b_type` = `b`.`b_type`)
    and (`a`.`b_panel` = `b`.`b_panel`)
    and (`a`.`b_conType` = `b`.`b_conType`)
```

If you do not need the null records use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.
One more suggestion, if you are using some language like php or asp.net remove cases from your query and do this work with server side language. this will increase the performance.

Comment: I will need the null values. Will try this one.

Comment: How come doing a simple self-join in MySQL takes a long time?

Comment: i assume you have many k records in your table. Moreover , you may not have added indexes therefore it becomes slow. One more thing you have cases which are causing the delay